# Unable to display image using django

Tags: python, django, image-upload

I am new to using django. In my app, I am uploading images that is being stored to the media folder. Now, I am trying to provide the link for downloading the image which is not working. I also tried to display the image directly( using img in html) which is not working either.

My code is as follows:

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


app_name = 'workers'

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name= 'index'),
url(r'^enrollment$',views.enroll, name='enroll'),
url(r'^save_enrollment$',views.save_enrollment, name='save_enrollment'),

]

if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Worker

class Worker_enrollment(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=250)
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=500)
    phone_number = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    designation = forms.CharField(max_length=1000)
    docfile = forms.FileField(label='select an image to upload')
    ssn = forms.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        model = Worker
        fields = ['name','address','phone_number','designation','docfile','ssn']
```

models.py:-

```
from django.db import models

class Worker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    docfile = models.ImageField(upload_to='documents/')
    ssn = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return (self.name)
```

views.py:-

```
from .models import  Worker
from .forms import Worker_enrollment
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.conf import settings

def index(request):
    workers_info = Worker.objects.all()
    context = {
    'workers':workers_info
}
return render(request, 'workers/index.html', context)

def enroll(request):
    form = Worker_enrollment(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        return render(request, 'workers/enroll.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = Worker_enrollment()
    return render(request, 'workers/enroll.html', {'form': form})

def save_enrollment(request):
    worker_info = Worker()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Worker_enrollment(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            worker_info.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            worker_info.address = form.cleaned_data['address']
            worker_info.designation = form.cleaned_data['designation']
            worker_info.phone_number = form.cleaned_data['phone_no']
            worker_info.ssn = form.cleaned_data['ssn']
            worker_info.docfile = request.FILES['docfile']
            worker_info.save()
            return render(request,'workers/saves_worker.html',{'worker_info':worker_info})
    else:
        form = Worker_enrollment()
    return render(request, 'workers/saves_worker.html', {'worker_info': worker_info})
```

enroll.html:-

```
<form action="save_enrollment" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_ul }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

saves_worker.html:-

```
<h1>Worker has been enrolled</h1>
<br>
<h2>Name - {{worker_info.name}}</h2><br>
<h2>PhoneNo - {{worker_info.phone_number}}</h2><br>
<h2>Designtion - {{worker_info.designation}}</h2><br>
<h2>SSN - {{worker_info.ssn}}</h2>
<h2>Address - {{worker_info.address}}</h2>
<h2><a href="{{ worker_info.docfile.url }}" >worker's image</h2>
```

The following are specified in the settings.py file:-

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
```

Comment: is `Worker_enrollment` a `modelform` or normal form ?

Comment: if you are using a `modelform` then I would suggest to have validations pass through the form and let it save the data rather than you creating an object of your `Wroker` model and saving it.

Comment: Its a model form. I did try it (ie, the suggestion given in the first answer). It didn't make any difference. The image is being stored in the media/documents folder). On clicking the image link its even showing media/documents/image_name.jpg in the url section, but the image is not opening.

Comment: there is one typo in your template `<h2><a href="{{ worker_info.docfile.url }}" >worker's image</h2>`. You should remove `worker's` and use something else like `worker image`

Comment: It did not make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your save_enrollment function saves the image in docfile field of the worker_info. Try using:

```
def save_enrollment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Worker_enrollment(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            worker_info = form.save()
            return render(request,'workers/saves_worker.html',{'worker_info':worker_info})
    else:
        form = Worker_enrollment()
    return render(request, 'workers/saves_worker.html', {'worker_info': worker_info}
```

Comment: I checked it. worker_info.docfile in the python shell gives <FieldFile: None>. The image is being saved in the Media/documents folder. Your code also gives the same result.                                                                  In save_worker.html I added the following if statement:- {% if worker_info.docfile %} and it returns true.

Comment: So you are not getting the docfile in your save_enrollment function after the form is validated but doing a check in the template returns true? And does your request carry any files?

Comment: The check in  the template returns true. I did not get the second part of the question. Can you please clarify it?

Comment: Is request.FILES carrying any file? Try print(request.FILES), print(worker_info.docfile) and let me know.

Comment: It returns <FieldFile: None>

Comment: Can you show the code of your Worker_enrollement form?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to define the fields again in your modelform. Also you are using `FileField` in the form instead of `ImageField`. If you want to add extra field in the form, you need to add those fields in `__init__()` method of form.
Try with the following:

```
class Worker_enrollment(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Worker
        fields = ['name','address','phone_number','designation','docfile','ssn']
```

**Extra tip**: Dont use `CharField` with `max_length=1000`. `CharField` should be used upto 255 characters. If you need more length use `TextField` instead. You also need to install `Pillow` library in order to make images visible.

Comment: I made the changes. The image is being saved in media/documents but on typing the following commands in the shell:                                                   a=Worker(pk=1)                                                                                              a.docfile                                                                                                                I get <ImageFieldFile: None> The image is not being displayed

Comment: is there only one object in your db? did you try with other primary keys ?

Comment: yes I did.                                                                                                         Not Found: /media/documents/passport_size_photograph_OhflV19.jpg        The above is being shown in the console but the jpg file is there in media/documents

Comment: I also checked the source code of the project.                                               <h2><img src="/media/documents/passport_size_photograph_MIOn6Wf.jpg" ></h2>

Comment: I am able to display the image, but I still don't understand why <ImageFieldFile: None> is returned

Comment: you need to use the manager in order to access the attributes of object. try this: `a = Worker.objects.get(pk=1)` and then `a.docfile`

Answer (score -1):

I just solved my problem by changing the MEDIA_URL as follows:

```
MEDIA_URL = 'shield/media/'
```

The name of my project is shield.